# Possible to link to another database link?

Tags: oracle

We have an existing database link in an Oracle database that links to data in a Sql Server database.  Now, a 2nd Oracle database needs to use that same data.  Due to security setup, the 2nd Oracle database cannot "see" the Sql Server database, but it can see the 1st Oracle database.

If we create a database link in the 2nd Oracle database that points to the 1st Oracle database, will we be able to query data from the Sql Server database in the 2nd Oracle database by going through 2 database links?  Would the query syntax look like this:

`SELECT * FROM myTable@2ndLink@1stLink`

Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this synthax would work (although it would be interesting to test it I can not do it right now). However, even if it doesn't work, you can still create a view in Database 1 that points to a table in your SQL Server Database. From Database 2, you could then query:

```
SELECT * FROM myView@db1
```

That would point to the correct table.

Comment: I am stepping through this and hit an unexpected error.  I created a view for myTable@1stLink in DB1 and I granted SELECT on that view to a different user in DB1.  Tried to SELECT from the view as User2 in DB1 and I get a username/password error.  I think the DB Link was created as CURRENT_USER and only that single user in DB1 has a valid username/password on the Sql Server database.  It will be a pain to get that user created anywhere else.  Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: @Shane: does the view work when you query it with the user that owns the view ?

Comment: I was able to create a new public database link that has the user/password in it.  That link and views created against it are working for all users.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Vincent's solution will work, and another solution is to create a synonym instead of a view.

```
DB1:
CREATE SYNONYM X FOR MyTable@sqlServerDB

DB2:
(assumes db link to DB1 connects as owner of synonym)
SELECT * from X@DB1
```

Comment: +1: synonyms will be easier to maintain than views (e.g. in case the source table adds/rename a column for example)