# Oracle DB Connection

Tags: oracle, networking, jdbc

I have 3 server. Server0 Server1 and Server2.

I have oracle installed in Server0.

Server1 has tnsnames.ora configured to connect to the oracle db in server0.

Server2 does not have access to server0.

Server2 has access to server1

Is there a way for server2 to connect to server0 through server1.

In Server2 i am trying to connect using JDBC. Appserver installed in Server2 is Tomcat.

Comment: You could probably create a db link

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094843/possible-to-link-to-another-database-link

Comment: no there is no two DB its just one DB that is in server0

Answer (score 0):

Access Your Database Remotely Through an SSH Tunnel:

```
# ssh -N -L [local port]:[database host]:[remote port] [username]@[remote host]
ssh -N -L 9998:<server0-ip>:1521 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem server1-user@<server1-ip>
sqlplus user/pass@localhost:9998/XE
```

Comment: i am primarily looking to establish connection through JDBC. Trying to see if i can use the server1 as proxy to connect to server0 from server2

Comment: JDBC connect string: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:9998/XE